# Calling Java Web Service from .NET Window Service issue

Tags: .net, web-services

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting "Unrecognised Message Version" exception error back when calling a web service written in java?

this is the stacktrace:
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Unrecognized message version.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception& requestException)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

Basically, all i have in hand is the endpoint address and login credentials. So what i did was putting that endpoint into IE and save it as WSDL file.

Then I run the WSDL file against Svcutil to generate the C# code. which I can then use in my window service to invoke the web service.

Is there anything wrong with that process?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The only thing wrong with the process is that you didn't tell us what went wrong. It's .NET. What do you meant that you "get an error". An exception was probably thrown. Please post the entire exception along with all inner exceptions.

Comment: added in some stacktrace